# Check for NULL pointer doesn't work for char pointer

Tags: c, if-statement, pointers, nullpointerexception, declaration

I know it must be silly to ask about, but my `if` statement that checks for null pointer doesn't seem to work. The code continues, and once I dereference the pointer, an error occurs. The code is kernel code, if that matters.

```c
// issue.h
static char *sys_efile[FILE_PATH_SIZE]; // 100

// issue_main.c
#include "issue.h"

if (sys_efile == NULL)
    return -EFAULT;

file = filp_open(*sys_efile, O_RDWR, 0);
```

```
BUG: kernel NULL pointer dereference, address: 0000000000000000
[   32.262950] #PF: supervisor read access in kernel mode
[   32.262952] #PF: error_code(0x0000) - not-present page
```

Do I miss smth?

Comment: `sys_efile` will never be null, it is an array, not a pointer. Maybe you meant to check one of the elements of the array?

Comment: @UnholySheep I thought about that. How can I look at the elements without dereferencing the pointer?

Comment: if `sys_efile` is a path (i.e. string), it should be defined as `static char  sys_efile[FILE_PATH_SIZE];` - i.e. an array of `char`s, not an array of `char*`.

Comment: `sys_efile` is *not* a pointer. Since it is an array you can safely access any valid index (so from 0 - `FILE_PATH_SIZE - 1`), e.g.: `sys_efile[0] == NULL`

Comment: @UnholySheep Wait what is the point of the `*` if you claim it's _not_ a pointer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You declared an array of pointers with static storage duration.

```
static char *sys_efile[FILE_PATH_SIZE];
```

So all elements of the array are implicitly initialized as null-pointers. But the array itself can not be implicitly converted to a null pointer because it occupies memory. So this statement

```
if (sys_efile == NULL)
```

will always evaluate to false.

Either actually instead of the array of pointers you want to declare a character array like

```
static char sys_efile[FILE_PATH_SIZE]; // 100
```

and then you may write for example

```
// issue_main.c
#include "issue.h"

if ( *sys_efile == '\0' )
    return -EFAULT;

file = filp_open( sys_efile, O_RDWR, 0);
```

Or if you are going to use an array of pointers then the if statement should look like

```
static char *sys_efile[FILE_PATH_SIZE]; // 100

// issue_main.c
#include "issue.h"

if ( *sys_efile == NULL)
    return -EFAULT;

file = filp_open(*sys_efile, O_RDWR, 0);
```

Comment: Note that `if ( *sys_efile == NULL )` aka `if ( sys_efile[0] == NULL )` (only) checks if the first pointer is `NULL`.

Comment: Thanks, I forgot the most basic stuff P:

Comment: @ikegami He is using only the first element in the shown call of file_open. I think that actually he needs to declare a character array.